# Use curl with a string input parameter in the url

Tags: macos, curl, postman

I want to use `curl` for a `GET` request, but the url is of the form:

`localhost:<port>/getter?key=This is a sentence.`, which means that the `key` is an input parameter in the endpoint.

If I use `POSTMAN` for the request, then the format with the spaces is absolutely fine.

I have a hard time giving the right format when I use `curl`. I have tried using the percentage symbol when we have spaces, but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
localhost:<port>/getter?key=This is a sentence
```

by

```
'http://localhost:<port>/getter?key=This%20is%20a%20sentence'
```

Note the `%20`.

If you want a command line to do it for you :

```
echo "/getter?key=This is a sentence" |
    perl -MURI::Escape -lne 'print uri_escape($_);'
```